# How to add the caption for a part of long table, which transferred to a new page?

Tags: tables, captions, longtable

I have a long table

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex

%%%
\documentclass[14pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX},Renderer=Basic} 
\setmainfont[Ligatures={TeX,Historic}]{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\frenchspacing

%%% Tables.
\usepackage{array,tabularx,tabulary,booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabu}
%

% Caption of Table
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[
singlelinecheck=false
]{caption}
\captionsetup{labelsep = space}
\usepackage[format=hang]{caption}
%

%%% Page
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=20mm}
\geometry{bottom=20mm}
\geometry{left=20mm}
\geometry{right=15mm}
%

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}[l]{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \caption{--- Caption of long table}
    \label{tableLabel} \\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Date} & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Values \\ of \\ balances\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Absolute \\ increases \end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Coefficients}&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Rates of growth, \\ \%\end{tabular}} \\ \cline{3-8} 
    &&chain& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}base\end{tabular}&chain& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}base\end{tabular}&chain&\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}base\end{tabular}\\ \hline
    1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\ \hline
    \endfirsthead
    %
    \multicolumn{8}{r}{Table continuation (Error Here) \ref{tableLabel}}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Date} & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Values \\ of \\ balances\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Absolute \\ increases, \\ млрд.руб.\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Coefficients}&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Rates of growth, \\ \%\end{tabular}} \\ \cline{3-8} 
    &&chain& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}base\end{tabular}&chain& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}base\end{tabular}&chain&\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}base\end{tabular}\\ \hline
    1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\ \hline
    \endhead
    %\hline
    \multicolumn{8}{r}{Table continuation \ref{tableLabel} on the next page\ldots}
    \endfoot
    \hline
    \endlastfoot
    %
    30.09.2014&1438&---&---&---&1&---&--- \\ \hline
    01.10.2014&1358,6&-79,4&-79,4&0,945&0,94&-5,5&-5,5 \\ \hline
    02.10.2014&796,3&-562,3&-641,7&0,586&0,55&-41,4&-44,6 \\ \hline
    03.10.2014&685,5&-110,8&-752,5&0,861&0,48&-13,9&-52,3 \\ \hline
    06.10.2014&574,8&-110,7&-863,2&0,839&0,4&-16,1&-60 \\ \hline
    07.10.2014&620,7&45,9&-817,3&1,08&0,43&8&-56,8 \\ \hline
    08.10.2014&696,9&76,2&-741,1&1,123&0,48&12,3&-51,5 \\ \hline
    09.10.2014&647,1&-49,8&-790,9&0,929&0,45&-7,1&-55 \\ \hline
    10.10.2014&734,6&87,5&-703,4&1,135&0,51&13,5&-48,9 \\ \hline
    13.10.2014&764,8&30,2&-673,2&1,041&0,53&4,1&-46,8 \\ \hline
    01.10.2014&1358,6&-79,4&-79,4&0,945&0,94&-5,5&-5,5 \\ \hline
    02.10.2014&796,3&-562,3&-641,7&0,586&0,55&-41,4&-44,6 \\ \hline
    03.10.2014&685,5&-110,8&-752,5&0,861&0,48&-13,9&-52,3 \\ \hline
    06.10.2014&574,8&-110,7&-863,2&0,839&0,4&-16,1&-60 \\ \hline
    07.10.2014&620,7&45,9&-817,3&1,08&0,43&8&-56,8 \\ \hline
    08.10.2014&696,9&76,2&-741,1&1,123&0,48&12,3&-51,5 \\ \hline
    09.10.2014&647,1&-49,8&-790,9&0,929&0,45&-7,1&-55 \\ \hline
    10.10.2014&734,6&87,5&-703,4&1,135&0,51&13,5&-48,9 \\ \hline
    13.10.2014&764,8&30,2&-673,2&1,041&0,53&4,1&-46,8 \\ \hline
    01.10.2014&1358,6&-79,4&-79,4&0,945&0,94&-5,5&-5,5 \\ \hline
    02.10.2014&796,3&-562,3&-641,7&0,586&0,55&-41,4&-44,6 \\ \hline
    03.10.2014&685,5&-110,8&-752,5&0,861&0,48&-13,9&-52,3 \\ \hline
    06.10.2014&574,8&-110,7&-863,2&0,839&0,4&-16,1&-60 \\ \hline
    07.10.2014&620,7&45,9&-817,3&1,08&0,43&8&-56,8 \\ \hline
    08.10.2014&696,9&76,2&-741,1&1,123&0,48&12,3&-51,5 \\ \hline
    09.10.2014&647,1&-49,8&-790,9&0,929&0,45&-7,1&-55 \\ \hline
    10.10.2014&734,6&87,5&-703,4&1,135&0,51&13,5&-48,9 \\ \hline
    13.10.2014&764,8&30,2&-673,2&1,041&0,53&4,1&-46,8 \\ \hline
    01.10.2014&1358,6&-79,4&-79,4&0,945&0,94&-5,5&-5,5 \\ \hline
    02.10.2014&796,3&-562,3&-641,7&0,586&0,55&-41,4&-44,6 \\ \hline
    03.10.2014&685,5&-110,8&-752,5&0,861&0,48&-13,9&-52,3 \\ \hline
    06.10.2014&574,8&-110,7&-863,2&0,839&0,4&-16,1&-60 \\ \hline
    07.10.2014&620,7&45,9&-817,3&1,08&0,43&8&-56,8 \\ \hline
    08.10.2014&696,9&76,2&-741,1&1,123&0,48&12,3&-51,5 \\ \hline
    09.10.2014&647,1&-49,8&-790,9&0,929&0,45&-7,1&-55 \\ \hline
    10.10.2014&734,6&87,5&-703,4&1,135&0,51&13,5&-48,9 \\ \hline
    13.10.2014&764,8&30,2&-673,2&1,041&0,53&4,1&-46,8 \\ \hline
    01.10.2014&1358,6&-79,4&-79,4&0,945&0,94&-5,5&-5,5 \\ \hline
    02.10.2014&796,3&-562,3&-641,7&0,586&0,55&-41,4&-44,6 \\ \hline
    03.10.2014&685,5&-110,8&-752,5&0,861&0,48&-13,9&-52,3 \\ \hline
    06.10.2014&574,8&-110,7&-863,2&0,839&0,4&-16,1&-60 \\ \hline
    07.10.2014&620,7&45,9&-817,3&1,08&0,43&8&-56,8 \\ \hline
    08.10.2014&696,9&76,2&-741,1&1,123&0,48&12,3&-51,5 \\ \hline
    09.10.2014&647,1&-49,8&-790,9&0,929&0,45&-7,1&-55 \\ \hline
    10.10.2014&734,6&87,5&-703,4&1,135&0,51&13,5&-48,9 \\ \hline
    13.10.2014&764,8&30,2&-673,2&1,041&0,53&4,1&-46,8 \\ \hline
    14.10.2014&1003,6&238,8&-434,4&1,312&0,7&31,2&-30,2
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

This table is obtained as follows on the picture:
[image]

As you can see on the picture, part of the table, which tranferred on the new page, have a caption "Table continuation (Error Here) 1". I made this caption using following code:

```
\multicolumn{8}{r}{Table continuation (Error Here) \ref{tableLabel}}
```

And this code was executed and issued the correct PDF file. But when executing the code, I got an errors:

```
Misplaced \noalign. ^^I\hline
Misplaced \omit. ^^I\multirow
Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. ^^I\multirow
```

How to solve the problem with this error?

P.S. If I delete this line:

```
\multicolumn{8}{r}{Table continuation (Error Here) \ref{tableLabel}}
```

errors does not occur. But the necessary caption will disappear.

Comment: you forgot to add `\\ ` to the line after `\endfirsthead` (it had to be `\multicolumn{8}{r}{Table continuation (Error Here) \ref{tableLabel}}`  `\\ `)

Comment: Thank you. That helped. I did not know about it:
\multicolumn{8}{r}{Table continuation (Error Here) \ref{tableLabel}} \\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your basic problem is solved by my comment above:

- each row before in table had to be terminated by `\\` or `\tabularnewline`
- table horizontal rules (except of line on the very beginning table) had to be after row termination

some off-topic issues:

i would redesign your table as show picture below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

i.e. use packages which you load in preamble (`booktabs`) and add two more: `makcell` for simplifying table code and `siunitx` for make for `S` column type, which enable numbers aligning at decimal points:

```
\documentclass[14pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX},Renderer=Basic}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={TeX,Historic}]{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\frenchspacing

%%% Tables.
\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow}
%
\usepackage{siunitx}

% Caption of Table
\usepackage[format=hang,
            labelsep = space,
            skip=1ex, 
            singlelinecheck=false]{caption}

%%% Page
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=20mm, bottom=20mm, left=20mm, right=15mm}

%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\sisetup{table-column-width=7.5ex}
\begin{longtable}[l]{c  S[table-format= 4.1]
                        S[table-format=-3.1]
                        S[table-format=-3.1]
                        S[table-format= 1.4]
                        S[table-format= 1.2]
                        S[table-format=-2.1]
                        S[table-format=-2.1]
                        }
\caption{--- Caption of long table}
    \label{tableLabel} \\
    \toprule
\multirow{3}{*}{Date}
        &   {\multirow{3}{*}{\makecell{Values of \\ balances}}}
            &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{Absolute \\ increases}}
                &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Coefficients}
                    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{Rates of\\ growth \%}} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){3-8}
        &   &   {chain}
                &   {base}
                    &   {chain}
                        &   {base}
                            &   {chain}
                                &   {base}                                  \\
    \midrule
    {1} & {2} & {3} & {4} & {5} & {6} & {7} & {8}                           \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
    %
\multicolumn{8}{r}{Table continuation \ref{tableLabel}}                     \\
    \midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{Date}
        &   {\multirow{3}{*}{\makecell{Values of \\ balances}}}
            &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{Absolute \\ increases}}
                &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Coefficients}
                    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{Rates of\\ growth \%}} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){3-8}
        &   &   {chain}
                &   {base}
                    &   {chain}
                        &   {base}
                            &   {chain}
                                &   {base}                                  \\
    \midrule
    {1} & {2} & {3} & {4} & {5} & {6} & {7} & {8}                           \\
    \midrule
\endhead
    \midrule
\multicolumn{8}{r}{Table continuation \ref{tableLabel} on the next page\ldots}
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
\endlastfoot
    %
30.09.2014  & 1438  & {--} & {--} & {--} & 1 & {--} & {--} \\
01.10.2014  & 1358,6&-79,4&-79,4&0,945&0,94&-5,5&-5,5 \\
02.10.2014&796,3&-562,3&-641,7&0,586&0,55&-41,4&-44,6 \\
03.10.2014&685,5&-110,8&-752,5&0,861&0,48&-13,9&-52,3 \\
06.10.2014&574,8&-110,7&-863,2&0,839&0,4&-16,1&-60 \\
    \addlinespace
07.10.2014&620,7&45,9&-817,3&1,08&0,43&8&-56,8 \\
08.10.2014&696,9&76,2&-741,1&1,123&0,48&12,3&-51,5 \\
09.10.2014&647,1&-49,8&-790,9&0,929&0,45&-7,1&-55 \\
10.10.2014&734,6&87,5&-703,4&1,135&0,51&13,5&-48,9 \\
13.10.2014&764,8&30,2&-673,2&1,041&0,53&4,1&-46,8 \\
    \addlinespace
01.10.2014&1358,6&-79,4&-79,4&0,945&0,94&-5,5&-5,5 \\
02.10.2014&796,3&-562,3&-641,7&0,586&0,55&-41,4&-44,6 \\
03.10.2014&685,5&-110,8&-752,5&0,861&0,48&-13,9&-52,3 \\
06.10.2014&574,8&-110,7&-863,2&0,839&0,4&-16,1&-60 \\
07.10.2014&620,7&45,9&-817,3&1,08&0,43&8&-56,8 \\
    \addlinespace
08.10.2014&696,9&76,2&-741,1&1,123&0,48&12,3&-51,5 \\
09.10.2014&647,1&-49,8&-790,9&0,929&0,45&-7,1&-55 \\
10.10.2014&734,6&87,5&-703,4&1,135&0,51&13,5&-48,9 \\
13.10.2014&764,8&30,2&-673,2&1,041&0,53&4,1&-46,8 \\
01.10.2014&1358,6&-79,4&-79,4&0,945&0,94&-5,5&-5,5 \\
    \addlinespace
02.10.2014&796,3&-562,3&-641,7&0,586&0,55&-41,4&-44,6 \\
03.10.2014&685,5&-110,8&-752,5&0,861&0,48&-13,9&-52,3 \\
06.10.2014&574,8&-110,7&-863,2&0,839&0,4&-16,1&-60 \\
07.10.2014&620,7&45,9&-817,3&1,08&0,43&8&-56,8 \\
08.10.2014&696,9&76,2&-741,1&1,123&0,48&12,3&-51,5 \\
    \addlinespace
09.10.2014&647,1&-49,8&-790,9&0,929&0,45&-7,1&-55 \\
10.10.2014&734,6&87,5&-703,4&1,135&0,51&13,5&-48,9 \\
13.10.2014&764,8&30,2&-673,2&1,041&0,53&4,1&-46,8 \\
01.10.2014&1358,6&-79,4&-79,4&0,945&0,94&-5,5&-5,5 \\
02.10.2014&796,3&-562,3&-641,7&0,586&0,55&-41,4&-44,6 \\
    \addlinespace
03.10.2014&685,5&-110,8&-752,5&0,861&0,48&-13,9&-52,3 \\
06.10.2014&574,8&-110,7&-863,2&0,839&0,4&-16,1&-60 \\
07.10.2014&620,7&45,9&-817,3&1,08&0,43&8&-56,8 \\
08.10.2014&696,9&76,2&-741,1&1,123&0,48&12,3&-51,5 \\
09.10.2014&647,1&-49,8&-790,9&0,929&0,45&-7,1&-55 \\
    \addlinespace
10.10.2014&734,6&87,5&-703,4&1,135&0,51&13,5&-48,9 \\
13.10.2014&764,8&30,2&-673,2&1,041&0,53&4,1&-46,8 \\
01.10.2014&1358,6&-79,4&-79,4&0,945&0,94&-5,5&-5,5 \\
02.10.2014&796,3&-562,3&-641,7&0,586&0,55&-41,4&-44,6 \\
03.10.2014&685,5&-110,8&-752,5&0,861&0,48&-13,9&-52,3 \\
    \addlinespace
06.10.2014&574,8&-110,7&-863,2&0,839&0,4&-16,1&-60 \\
07.10.2014&620,7&45,9&-817,3&1,08&0,43&8&-56,8 \\
08.10.2014&696,9&76,2&-741,1&1,123&0,48&12,3&-51,5 \\
09.10.2014&647,1&-49,8&-790,9&0,929&0,45&-7,1&-55 \\
10.10.2014&734,6&87,5&-703,4&1,135&0,51&13,5&-48,9 \\
    \addlinespace
13.10.2014&764,8&30,2&-673,2&1,041&0,53&4,1&-46,8 \\
14.10.2014&1003,6&238,8&-434,4&1,312&0,7&31,2&-30,2
\end{longtable}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: How did you make "stair" of the code?

Comment: @ERAFY, i try to make code in editor similar as possible to final look of table. however, when cell content is long, than i usual put content of each cell in new row as you can see in my table code. that is just my way to set tables. you can do this as you wish or how it is more convenient to you.